# Why one code is so much better than the other code?

Tags: c++, performance, c++14

I was solving a question on leetcode and when I wrote the code I got 5% rating in my time complexity so I went to other people's code and I found some which was getting 83% rating and was 10x faster than my code but when I tried to understand why that code is soo much better I couldn't figure it out.
Can you please tell me Why my code is soo much slower

MY CODE:-

```
string ans;
    string tree2str(TreeNode* root) {
        if(root==nullptr)
        {
            return ans;
        }
        string temp = to_string(root->val);
        ans = ans+temp;
        if(root->left!=nullptr)
        {
            ans.push_back('(');
            tree2str(root->left);
            ans.push_back(')');
        }
        if(root->left==nullptr&&root->right!=nullptr)
        {
            ans.push_back('(');
            ans.push_back(')');
        }
        if(root->right!=nullptr)
        {
            ans.push_back('(');
            tree2str(root->right);
            ans.push_back(')');
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

BETTER CODE:-

```
string tree2str(TreeNode *t) {
    string ret = "";
    
    if(t == NULL){
        return(ret);
    }

    traverse(t, ret);
    
    return(ret);
}

private:

void traverse(TreeNode *node, string &ret){
    
    //first val does not get pre-pended (
    if(ret != ""){
        ret += "(";
    }
    ret += to_string(node->val);

    //if there is no left node but there is a right node, need to write () to
    //represent the left node per the problem description
    if(node->left == NULL && node->right != NULL){
        ret += "()";
    }
    
    //close paren on non-null left node
    if(node->left != NULL){
        traverse(node->left, ret);
        ret += ")";
    }

    //close paren on non-null right node
    if(node->right != NULL){
        traverse(node->right, ret);
        ret += ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is doing a whole lot of copying, whereas the other solution you posted just appends stuff onto one string.

Comment: If/when you fix that, your method will ultimately do a boatload of string copying too. The faster method drives one string object by-reference throughout the entire harvest that is continually accumulated. The outer-most interface, `tree2str` is a front-end to declare that string, then run the `traverse`, supplying it as that second argument.

Comment: Whereas you have same complexity for the main algorithm, you have (hidden) copies of string at each recursion (which even change global complexity).

Comment: These challenge/competitive coding web sites are mostly for highly skilled, experienced C++ hackers to spend some free time solving useless coding puzzles. Trying to learn C++ from them is like trying to learn ice-skating by playing a hockey game against a team consisting of Wayne Gretzky, Mario Lemiuex, Sidney Crosby, Mark Messier, Brian Leetch, and Phil Esposito. It's going to be far more productive to learn C++, first, using any number of reputable, edited, textbooks; and then try your luck at competitive coding or challenge/competition sites.

Comment: @Jarod42 But where is the copies happening at push_back() ? Is it slower to push_back than to use +=??

Comment: @paddy  But where is the copies happening at push_back() ? Is it slower to push_back than to use +=??

Comment: @chirayuaggarwal43: Your recursive call `tree2str(root->left);` creates a (discarded) copy of `ans`.

Comment: As every C++ textbook would explain, both `push_back` and `+=` can reallocate, therefore copy everything. `std::string` is contiguous storage, like `std::vector`. You can't avoid copying, when growing its size. This is fundamental. As one would learn in a textbook there are ways to minimize the copying. It is quite clear that this coding puzzle's trick is to estimate the final size of the string, then `reserve()` the estimated size, thus eliminating most of the copying (hopefully) when creating the string.

Comment: `to_string` appears to return a new string object. I am not sure it is `std::to_string` or not but creating new string is a bit expensive (though small string can be optimized so not to allocate anything on the heap). This makes `std::to_string` not very efficient in practice (IDK why the designers of the STL choose to do this). Using `sprintf` from the C language is generally much faster (unfortunately). Same for `atoi`.

Answer (score 2):

> std::string operator+ allocates a new string and copies the two
> operand strings every time. repeat many times and it gets expensive,
> O(n).
>
> std::string append and operator+= on the other hand, bump the capacity
> by 50% every time the string needs to grow. Which reduces the number
> of memory allocations and copy operations significantly, O(log n).

So, I made the [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/fr5ae6TfG). As you see if you change

```
string temp = to_string(root->val);
ans = ans+temp;
```

to

```
ans += to_string(root->val);;
```

then you can reduce time to run like this. Not better than code you mentioned but not too bad.

[image]